# Count the number A-Objects that have B-Object as a a foreign key

Tags: soql, custom-object, lookup

I have two custom objects, Students and Coaches, where Students have a Coach__c lookup field. I am attempting to write a trigger that when a new Student is created, I need to assign that student a Coach.

In order to do this, I need to find out which Coach has the least amount of students, and assign the new student to that coach. In normal SQL, I would use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT c.id, count(s.Coach__c) AS number_of_students
FROM Coach__c AS c
LEFT JOIN Student__c AS s
ON (c.id == s.Coach__c)
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY number_of_students
LIMIT 1
```

How would I achieve this goal in SOQL?

Or is there a way in which I could count the number of Student__C relationships that Coach__c is used in via the Coach__c object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SOQL group by clause, In your insert trigger you can use the Aggregate function count on Student table, to group student number vs coachId

```
   AggregateResult[] groupedResults =[SELECT Coach__c ,count(Id) FROM Student__c 
                                    GROUP BY Coach__c];
```

Then sort them with one which is least assigned and then assign the newly created student to it.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Comment: Can even do the sorting and selection in SOQL as in the SQL: `... GROUP BY Coach__c ORDER BY count(Id) ASC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Ah, I  literally forgot about it

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, @DavidReed I also added `... FROM Student__c WHERE Coach__c != '' GROUP BY...` so that empty coaches aren't considered during query